# Snowflake: Allow users to alter their RSA_PUBLIC_KEY property

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Snowflake user has the SYSADMIN role; however, I would like to be able to change my RSA_PUBLIC_KEY and RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_2 properties myself. Is there a combination of Roles and privileges that could be created to allow a user to modify only their RSA_PUBLIC_KEY and RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_2 properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not one of the properties that a user can change themselves: 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

More specifically, securityadmin (or accountadmin) role is required: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html

Also discussed here:
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Q8cYtSAJ/createalter-user

*** UPDATE ***

As a workaround, create a stored procedure owned by the SECURITYADMIN role, with the EXECUTE AS OWNER option in the definition, and grant access to to your users:

```
use role securityadmin;

create or replace procedure p_set_rsa_key_for_user_x(RSA_KEY string) 
returns text
language javascript
execute as owner
as
  $$
  const stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ 
    sqlText: "alter user user_x set RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = ?",
    binds: [RSA_KEY] 
  })
  const rs = stmt.execute()
  return 'SUCCESS'
  $$
;

grant usage on procedure p_set_rsa_key_for_user_x(string) to role analyst;

use role analyst;

call p_set_rsa_key_for_user_x('MIIBIjANBgkqh...');
```

Where 'user_x' is the username in question, and 'analyst' is a role they've been granted.

Hope that's helpful...

Comment: The short answer is NO? There is no way to add a custom Role on a custom set of properties to allow a specific user to update their own rsa_public_key.

Comment: That's how I read the docs.  But it seems like there is a workaround.  The securityadmin role can create stored procedure that executes the ALTER statement, and then grant access to the stored procedure to other roles.  The trick is to include the "EXECUTE AS OWNER" option in the stored procedure definition.   I'll amend my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example in case if you want one general procedure which allow rotate only user owned key.

```sql
use role securityadmin;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SET_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY(RSA_PUBLIC_KEY VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
    LANGUAGE SQL
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
      user VARCHAR DEFAULT (SELECT CURRENT_USER());
    BEGIN
      alter user IDENTIFIER(:user) set RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = :RSA_PUBLIC_KEY;
      return 'Success';
    END;
    $$;
grant usage on procedure SET_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY(string) to role public;
call SET_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY('MIIBIjANBgkqh...');
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't technically needed but might be an idea to add a check to see if the user executing the Stored Procedure is the person(s) for which this SP has been provided. Add "select current_user()" into the code and test against a user name to improve the security perhaps...

Comment: agreed. I thought the exact same thing. We wouldn't want someone updating the Security Admin user with just any old key.